# How to update ParentID field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some records that were imported to SQL. One of the fields 'FieldToChage' was a ParentID that referenced an old key value. When I imported the data to SQL, the new key value does not correspond with the old key value contained in 'FieldToChage'.

Here is simplified schema of my imported table:

```
[dbo].[zChangeTable](
      [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [FieldToChange] [int] NULL,
      [OldID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

What i need is the field titled 'FieldToChange' (ParentID) to reference the new key value with the old index in field 'OldID'.

Here is a sample of the existing table data:

```
ID      FieldToChange   OldID
159      NULL            143
160      143             142
161      143             145
25       174             171
26       174             172
204      NULL            173
17       NULL            174
```

So an update statement is needed that walks thru the table and updates the 'FieldToChange' as shown below...

```
ID      FieldToChange   OldID
159      NULL            143
160      159             142
161      159             145
25       17              171
26       17              172
204      NULL            173
17       NULL            174
```

hope this makes sense...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t
SET t.FieldToChange = t1.ID
FROM zChangeTable t JOIN zChangeTable t1 ON t.FieldToChange = t1.OldID
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
update zChangeTable
set t1.FieldToChange = t2.ID
from zChangeTable t1
inner join zChangeTable t2 on t1.FieldToChange = t2.OldID
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to do the import in two parts: first adding the records, then going back and assigning the parent ID column. For the sake of simplicity, I'll use the table names `OldTable` and `NewTable`

```
insert into NewTable
(
    OldID
)
select
    ID

from OldTable

update nt set
    FieldToChange = ntp.ID

from NewTable nt

join OldTable ot on ot.ID = nt.OldID
join NewTable ntp on ntp.OldID = ot.ParentID
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this would be to import the table with Identity Insert enabled and preserve the values in the identity column "ID".

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT zChangeTable ON
GO
/* Import the data, including values for ID */
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT zChangeTable OFF
GO
```